# TikZ: avoid branch in tree

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-trees

[image]

I want an optic like this, but without the crossed out branch. 
What do I have to do?

```
\documentclass[border=10pt, tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[sibling distance=10em,
  every node/.style = {shape=rectangle, rounded corners,
    draw, align=center,
    top color=white, bottom color=blue!20}]
\node {A0}
child { node {A1} 
        child{ node{A1.1}               
              child{ node{X} }               
              child[draw=none]{  }% no effect, problem here .............................
              }
        child{ node{A1.2} 
               }
        };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The style of the edge is controlled by `edge from parent`, which is `draw` by default. Hence,

```
\documentclass[border=10pt, tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[sibling distance=10em,
  every node/.style = {shape=rectangle, rounded corners,
    draw, align=center,
    top color=white, bottom color=blue!20}]
\node {A0}
child { node {A1} 
        child{ node{A1.1}               
              child{ node{X} }               
              child[draw=none, edge from parent/.style={}]{  }% no effect, problem here .............................
              }
        child{ node{A1.2} 
               }
        };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

omits the edge:

[image: tree with missing edge]

[I would use `forest`, but your kilometres may vary.]